# Getting rid of container div

Tags: html, css

it seems to be a common practice to use a div with a class of “container” or “content” or something similar around the main content to help with the css-design of the page.

I personally don't like that, because it is (in my opinion) a violation of the rule to seperate presentation from content (because the -element serves no semantic purpose).

So my question is: Is there any way to get a similar result with just CSS? To be more specific, I want the site to have a background-image, but to have a solid white background around the main content.

I already tried something like setting two backgrounds for , one the image, the second a solid white and then size the second one down, but I guess, you can only use background-size on images?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good luck there. I tried several options to have my site centered, but when I found a solution that worked, it didn't work in certain browsers, and to make them work it would require to add other stuff, so defeating the purpose.  My suggestion, forget the purism and just learn to ignore that little <div id='container'></div> around your html. Really, you'll be a happier person :)

Comment: Well, a "container" is semantic - it groups things together (even if it's your whole page). If you're a purist, then use the html5 'section' or 'article' element.

Comment: Hm it's not purely puritanical. I actually want to be able to use completely different themes, so to put a div there just so this one design looks good might break things in other themes. ;) And okay, I did not seem to have make myself clear: Yes, a container is semantical, because it groups things together, that is exactly my problem. If it is a pure design element it should leave the semantics alone and not group things together that do not belong together (”content“ is a relative term after all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `html` or `body` elements, except this is problematic across various browsers, which is why people frequently use a div.

Comment: Well, it seems to work that way at least in firefox and chromium. It's not the only thing I use, that requires a recent browser, so maybe I might just settle for that for now.

Comment: You may well get away with it if you ignore some older browsers that are more and more ignorable these days.